# How to show recent edits and currently selected line on the scrollbar like Visual Studio?

Tags: php, plugins, ide, scrollbar, phpstorm

When I edit a file in Visual Studio, vertical tags appears in the scrollbar to track the lines I edited in the current session.

Like this:

[image: Screenshot of Visual Studio scrollbar.]

1. *Vertical tag to track current session's edits area*
2. *Minor question: is there a way to increase the width of the scrollbar?*
3. *How do I show the line where the insertion point is like this?*

How do I get something like that in PhpStorm2016.3.2? Is there a setting or a plugin to do that?

I know I can jump to last edits with keyboard but I'd like a visual confirmation of where my edits are.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this?

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.3/general.html

> "Highlight modified lines in gutter
>
> Select this check box if you want added/modified lines to be
>   highlighted with a color stripe in the left editor gutter.
>
> Different color for lines with whitespace-only modifications
>
> This option only becomes available if the Highlight modified lines in
>   gutter option is enabled.
>
> Select this check box if you want lines where only whitespaces were
>   added/removed to be highlighted with a different color from lines with
>   more significant modifications."

Comment: That's strange: if i check that box nothing appears!